# laravel 5 display books with author name

Tags: relationship, laravel-5

How do I display books with the author name?
Here is my model:

**Book.php**

```
public function authors()
{
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
}
```

**Author.php**

```
public function books()
{
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
}
```

My controller:

**BookController.php**

```
use App\Author;


public function index()
{
    foreach (Book::with('authors')->get() as $book)
    {
        echo $book->authors->name;
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

> Trying to get property of non-object

Please HELP what might be the problem?

Comment: Although eloquent is pretty smart, I always find that defining foreign keys in relationships makes them more reliable. Incidentally, shouldn't `authors()` in your book model be singular if you're using `belongsTo()`?

Comment: thanks it worked after changing it to singular ...GREAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will display only author name for each book.

Instead use this code that returns all books with authors.

```
public function index()    
{     
    $books = Book::with('author')->get();

    return $books;
}
```